# File permissions in AppData folder

Tags: c#, file-permissions

i have an XML file that i need to change an element in. I was testing my application with the file copied to my desktop, and its works fine.

By default, the XML file will be located in C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Roaming\direc

My application uses

```
string pathToXml = @"C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Roaming\direc\cqn.xml";
```

to pass the path to my function that does the change i need it to.

But now i am getting a Access to the path is denied error. Now i know this question has been asked before, so my apologies for that. But what i am searching isnt helping unfortunately.

- Running W8 x64 as an Admin with UAC switched off
- Running Visual Studio as admin doesnt help (as suggested in another thread)
- Running the built .exe file as admin doesnt help
- The file and folder does exist, and is not being used by another process.

I tried adding this just above the part that edits the file, but no luck:

```
            FileSecurity fSec = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(pathToXml);
        fSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName,
            FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        File.SetAccessControl(pathToXml, fSec);

        DirectorySecurity dSec = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(pathToXml);
        dSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName,
            FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post the exception verbatim and the line of code which is throwing it.

Comment: Hi, i get UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled, access to the path "C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Roaming\direc" is denied. The line of code that throws it is XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);